# how to write value on image through using excel , csv

Tags: php, photoshop

I have a lot of names in excel sheet. I want to write them one by one on an image. Image is repeated. The same image shows one name. 
Please, tell me how to write code /manual /using Photoshop or other method.
http://prntscr.com/kowpr4

Comment: Consider including images directly into the body of your question.  This way, if prntscr.com goes out of business, folks will still be able to understand your question by reading it on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @ctt New users are specifically prevented from embedding images due to the potential for abuse.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I would recommend you export your spreadsheet to some open, non-Microsoft, non-proprietary format, such as a CSV file.

Let's assume it looks like this and is called `"names.csv"`:

```
William, Gates
Kermit, Frog
```

Now, grab a copy of the indispensable **ImageMagick** and install it.

Now you need to generate a decent quality badge image rather than the horrible one you linked to. I made mine 1200x760 - so grab this one if you want things to align properly:

[image]

Then you will need a script to iterate through the list of names. I am doing it with `bash` but you can use Windows `for` loop, like [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=1
while IFS=', ' read first last; do
   filename="badge-$counter.jpg"
   echo Generating file $filename, for $first, $last

   magick -font ComicSansMSB -background none -fill magenta -size 420x60 caption:"$first" first.png
   magick -font Verdana      -background none -fill blue    -size 420x60 caption:"$last"  last.png
   magick badge.png first.png -geometry +710+360 first.png -composite last.png -geometry +710+460 -composite "$filename"
   ((counter+=1))
done < names.csv
```

So, for each line in the file, I read the first name and surname. I have a counter that increments for each file (`i`) so that I can generate a unique filename.

I then make a little image, sized to match the text field, called `"first.png` with the first name. Likewise for the surname, a file called `"last.png"`. I do them in different fonts and colours just for fun and so you can see how to do it. I then load up the badge template, and after setting the correct position, composite the names onto the badges and save with unique filenames.

[image]

[image]

---

I have marked up an image so you can see where the dimensions come from:

[image]

---

**Keywords**: ImageMagick, form-filling, form completion, badge, name badge, automated, automatic, scripted, command-line, command line, Excel, CSV.