# Photoshop datasets and variables from csv limited to 99?

Tags: png, photoshop

We're using Photoshops ability to import datasets from CSV to produce some ID cards for an event. We merge separate PNG's together and the output them using the "Export/Datasets as files" function

The CSV is set up as

```
|ID | Image1        |Image 2        |
| - | ------------- |---------------|
| 1 | path to X.png | path to Z.png |
| 2 | path to Y.png | path to W.png |
```

Repeated for about 200 rows with different images.

The issue we have is anything beyond the 99th row pulls the error

"Could not apply the dataset as the replacement file was not found" There are no issues with the file paths. If you substitute a post 100 row into a row pre 100 it works fine.

As if there is a hard limit of the number of rows we can have in a imported csv. I can't find any documentation from adobe as to any hard limit. And this "bug" is present in both a copy of cs6 and photoshop 2021. 1-99 work absolutely perfectly.

Does anyone have any workarounds. Or an alternative method of doing this?

Comment: This may be an alternative... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115925/2836621

Comment: I don't think there is a limit to any .CSV values. However, are images still left open in Photoshop - which there is a limit of 99 documents?